# Pygame - how do I remove only one life? more than one is removed with each collision

Tags: python, pygame, collision

Not all the code - just the player class, if more detail is needed let me know

```
class Player(Entity):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        Entity.__init__(self)
        self.xvel = 0
        self.yvel = 0
        self.onGround = False
        self.image = Surface((32,32))
        self.lives = 3
        self.image = stand
        self.rect = Rect(x, y, 64, 64)

    def update(self, up, down, left, right, running, platforms, enemygroup, 
attack):
        if attack:
            self.image = attack
        if up: #in air

            if self.onGround: self.yvel -= 10 #if player hits the ground 
 then move up
            if self.image == walk1:
                self.image = jump1
            if self.image == walk_flip:
                self.image = jump_flip

        if down:
            pass #do nothing
        if running:
            self.xvel = 12
        if left:
            self.xvel = -8 #differennt movement velocities
            self.image = walk_flip
        if right:
            self.xvel = 8
            self.image = walk1

        if not self.onGround:
            self.yvel += 0.3
            if self.yvel > 100: self.yvel = 100 #can't fall faster than 100 
pixels
        if not(left or right):
            self.xvel = 0 #no movement
        self.rect.left += self.xvel
        self.collide(self.xvel, 0, platforms, enemygroup)
        self.rect.top += self.yvel
        self.onGround = False;
        self.collide(0, self.yvel, platforms, enemygroup)

        #self.updatecharacter(walk1)
    def collide(self, xvel, yvel, platforms, enemygroup):
        for p in platforms:
            if pygame.sprite.collide_rect(self, p): #compares rect value of 
player and platform
                if isinstance(p, ExitBlock):
                    pygame.event.post(pygame.event.Event(QUIT))
                if xvel > 0:
                    self.rect.right = p.rect.left #right of the playr 
collides left of platform
                    print ("collide right")
            if xvel < 0:
                self.rect.left = p.rect.right #left of player collide right of platform
                print ("collide left")
            if yvel > 0:
                self.rect.bottom = p.rect.top
                self.onGround = True
                self.yvel = 0
            if yvel < 0:
                self.rect.top = p.rect.bottom
```

This is the collision section of my code for the player and collision with enemys. The idea is to remove lifes starting at 3 to 0. when 0 lives are reached the intro is played again as a restart. However, all the lives are lost at once as soon as the player collides with the enemy.

```
    for i in enemygroup:
        if pygame.sprite.collide_rect(self, i):
            boom = self.rect.bottom - i.rect.top
            if enemy.destroyed == False:
                enemy.destroyed = True
                self.lives = self.lives - 1
                enemy.destroyed = True


            if boom <= 8 and enemy.destroyed == False:
                self.yvel = - 8
                enemy.destroyed = False
            if self.lives == 0:
                game_intro()
```

Comment: That's a lot of code to have to go through, but I'd guess that it *is* only subtracting one life per collision. The problem is more likely that many collisions are triggering in a row. Maybe you need to make it so only one collision is triggered every second or something.

Comment: any idea how to trigger once every second?

Comment: I don't know pygame, but you could set a boolean variable on collision to true, only trigger another collision if its false, and reset it back to true a second later using a timer.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should already work: the lives to your player depend on the state of `enemy.destroyed`. After your player collides with enemy and loses a life, the `enemy.destroyed` becomes true. After that, the `enemy` instance will have no effect on the player lives (assuming that was the only way for the enemy to take down a player). Note: you reassign `enemy.destroyed` twice to `True`, which is unnecesary.

```
enemy.destroyed = False
conditions = True  # conditions can include collision with enemy
def statements():
    pass # just your statements that you want to run

while True:
    if not enemy.destroyed and conditions: # no need for == True/False
        enemy.destroyed = True
        print("Enemy destroyed!")
        statements()
```

Here I have kind of modeled your situation. The `statements()` function will be run only once, because the conditions are only ever true once. If some of this doesn't make sense or doesn't exactly work, tell me, maybe including more code (what is `enemy` and what is the true purpose of `enemy.destroyed`).